# Dynamic Variable Parameter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I feel like this isn't possible but I thought I would ask anyway. I have a short piece of code that I'm intending to use to add weeks/months/year to a given date. The time frame chosen will be dependent on a string passed. My question is when it comes to something like `relativedelta` is it possible to dynamically choose with parameter to use? So if the string passed is "weeks" then it would pass `relativedelta(weeks=1)` and if "months" it would pass `relativedelta(months=1)`? I've attached my code which I know doesn't work but it's just to illustrate what I'm imagining.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

today = datetime.today()

print(today)
print(today + relativedelta(months=2))

loop = 1
for i in range(5):
    variable_weeks = 'weeks'
    next_month = today + relativedelta(variable_weeks=loop)
    date_string = next_month.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print(date_string)
    loop += 1
```

Comment: The arguments to relativedelta are keyword arguments so you can construct a dict of arguments e.g. `d={"weeks":2}` or `d={"years":3, "days":2}` and then call `relativedelta(**d)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
...
variable_weeks = 'weeks'
next_month = today + relativedelta(**{variable_weeks: loop})
...
```

This uses a dict for the key-value pairs that you can define with variables. The dict is then unpacked as the input for relativedelta.